# Duplicating or importing function apps in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an existing function app i would need to either duplicate or import. The only small changes needed in the new copies can be done manually so i'm just trying to make the process as automatic as possible without copying/pasting anything from my intial function app.

I did find a button to "download the app content" locally on my computer but i can't find any informations about how i should import this package.

Does anyone know more about this ?
Thanks you in avance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have found `download the app content`, the next step is to deploy this zip file to the new function app.

In browser go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeploy`, and directly drag the zip file there.

See [Zip Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) for other methods using REST API and Azure CLi.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help